# Eager Loading N+1 issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, eager-loading

```
 <%- @lessons.includes(:bookmarks).each_with_index do |lesson, index| -%>
          <tr>
            <td class="w6 pl">
              <%- bookmark = lesson.bookmarks.where(user_id: current_user).first -%>
              <%= render :partial => "student/lessons/bookmark", :locals => {:bookmark => bookmark, :lesson => lesson} %>
            </td>
          </tr>
 <%- end -%>
```

The above code produces the following N+1 queries:

```
  Bookmark Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "bookmarks".* FROM "bookmarks" WHERE "bookmarks"."lesson_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
  Bookmark Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "bookmarks".* FROM "bookmarks" WHERE "bookmarks"."lesson_id" = 1 AND "bookmarks"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Rendered student/lessons/_bookmark.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Bookmark Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "bookmarks".* FROM "bookmarks" WHERE "bookmarks"."lesson_id" = 2 AND "bookmarks"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Rendered student/lessons/_bookmark.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Bookmark Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "bookmarks".* FROM "bookmarks" WHERE "bookmarks"."lesson_id" = 3 AND "bookmarks"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Rendered student/lessons/_bookmark.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Bookmark Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "bookmarks".* FROM "bookmarks" WHERE "bookmarks"."lesson_id" = 4 AND "bookmarks"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Rendered student/lessons/_bookmark.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Bookmark Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "bookmarks".* FROM "bookmarks" WHERE "bookmarks"."lesson_id" = 5 AND "bookmarks"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Rendered student/lessons/_bookmark.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Bookmark Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "bookmarks".* FROM "bookmarks" WHERE "bookmarks"."lesson_id" = 6 AND "bookmarks"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
```

How do I prevent the additionally queries after the first one since I'm using a where query inside the loop?

Thanks!

Comment: `@lessons.includes(:bookmarks).where(bookmarks: {user_id: current_user.id}).each_with_index` and then `bookmark = lesson.bookmarks.first`?

Comment: Yep, thanks!  I knew I was missing something simple.

Comment: EDIT:
Actually this query will then only return lessons with bookmarks.  I want to return all lessons, but be able to know if the lesson has a bookmark or not and get the bookmark if the lesson has one.

Comment: so you can't use eager loading in your case. you need to do two queries manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do two queries manually:

```
@lessons = Lesson.all # i.e.
@bookmarks = Bookmark.select("bookmarks.*, DISTINCT(lesson_id)").where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

And then

```
@lessons.each do |lesson|
  ...
  bookmark = @bookmarks.detect{ |b| b.lesson_id == lesson.id }
  ...
end
```

Comment: Getting a postgres error for using .group(:lesson_id)
SELECT "bookmarks".* FROM "bookmarks" WHERE "bookmarks"."user_id" = 1 GROUP BY bookmarks.lesson_id
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column "bookmarks.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Oh, postgre. You can try use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`. I'll update my answer. And I am not sure if it will work with postgre :)

Comment: @fl00r: The name of the RDBMS is `PostgreSQL` or `Postgres` for short. Ain't no such thing as "postgre".